# USB microphone has static on Pi, but is fine on Windows

Tags: usb, audio

I have [this USB mic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IR8R7WQ) and the  Pi 3.

When I plug this mic into my Windows computer, it sounds fine.

But when I plug this mic into the Pi and record a clip, there is a lot of static. You can faintly make out that words are being spoken but that's about it.

[Listen to both clips here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2pVa3_C-lNud1RNVm5oc3VIZkU)

For some reason, the USB mic does not work well on the Pi.
 Does anyone have a way to make the mic work on the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several USB microphones that all work fine under Windows, but not all of them work well with the Pi.

Interestingly, the ones that do not work well with the Pi also do not work well with my Android tablet.  Can't explain why; That's just the way it is.

One alternative is to pick up one of those $7 USB sound cards - they work great with Pi, and use a microphone with a 1/8" plug with it.

I've had 100% success with them, plus if you also use it for sound output it gives cleaner audio than the Pi itself.  I use a 4-port USB 3 micro-hub so everything fits.

They are available from the usual sources.

Guaranteed results.  No muss, no fuss.  They just plain work.

Comment: Here are the ones I use:  https://smile.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-2-Pack-Adapter-Windows/dp/B012E4CUPC  - I use them on all my PCs, including the one with the big screen I use for Netflix - with speakers all around the room -  and also on my Android tablet and on the one Rpi that I use to monitor the others.  I also run a low-power radio station and use one of these to feed from the ancient PC that picks up the stream from the Internet and feeds it to the mixer.  They do produce very good sound.They are universal.  Have fun!

Comment: While you're at it, here is the least expensive way to make a very nice little audio system for your Pi. You need a 1/8" to 2 RCA cable to connect, and a CCTV-style 12V power supply to run it, but it sounds great.  (You can also use a Y-connector and split it off for your home stereo if you like).   
 https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B007TUSXEY and https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B000MCGF1O

Comment: I'm happy for you.  I think they are terrific.  I keep spares, even.

Comment: That's a start.  Just keep coming back.  There is a lot to be learned here.   Cheers!